# How can i get the HTML5 Local storage values in server side

Tags: javascript, html, c#-4.0, local-storage

I am a .Net developer, I know that the HTM5 localstorage is client-side storage technique. I want to get the local storage data on the server-side.

For getting cookie value from server-side we have `Request.Cookie` in ASP.NET. Is there any solution like that to take the local storage value directly on the server-side? Please guide me. I am using the .net 4.0 framework

Thanks,
Jibu

Answer (score 15):

You will need to pass this information from the client to the server using standard HTTP techniques. Using javascript you could fill:

- Hidden fields
- Query string parameters
- POST
- Ajax call to the server
- ...

It will all depend on how your application is organized, what kind of information is being stored, its volume, whether you want to redirect or not, ... But in all cases this should be done using javascript since that's the only way to access data stored in localStorage.

Answer (score 13):

No. The whole point of local storage is that it is local. One of the advantages of it over cookies is that you can store lots of data in it. One of the advantages of cookies is that they are tiny so the overhead of including them in every HTTP request to a given host is small. There two advantages are incompatible so you won't want them in a single technology.

If you want to get the data on the server, then you need to get the client to send it explicitly (e.g. via Ajax).

Answer (score 0):

This is a widescope question. (like the length of a piece of string), but Ill try to make this helpful:

- If you have values in local store in webserver I assume your webserver is JSON? Or did you use the sql local storage option?

1. Regardless of type of storage, you need to build an interface that both handles:

a) Reading data from your local database -> its important to involve some kind of date or index value in here if you are aiming to sync databases... this is to make sure you send  IN ORDER all transactions / updates which are in your database. For this to happen you must store your data not only as tables with inforamtion but also tables that contain events of when updates happened and what was updated. (change tables). This will help check in the server end that everything is sync and also means you dont send data to the server that is not needed and can be kept locally. ((otherwise what is the point of local store if you cant save yourself server database space by only syncing waht is necessary?)

b) A HTTP local server to send the data to your destination client server or database server, etc (however you have set your infrastructure) - I recommend using industry standards for your language and server, which is Ajax and JQuery. If you do a lot of streaming of data then i recommend looking into RXjs with Ajax to get a http interface built (interface in this sense just means a way to expose your client like an API and post http calls)

c) An event loop to handle how often and what triggers the synchronization so that you dont destroy your users machine with overdoing it (you dont want to do this too often, but also want to it to be meaninful rather than "every night" maybe user enabled whenever you detect an event which triggers wifi available again.) - i recommend using native wifi reading capabilities built into Apache Cordova and also industry standards for your server setup (for example Express.js for Node.JS).

2. Obviously the backend server needs to have its API set up and authentication  / authorizations, etc.