# How to read the localstorage values at server side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, local-storage

I am using localstorage to maintain the data at client side in MVC.

I need to read the localstorage data in MVC controller. Is this possible?

If it is, please give me the solution how to do it.

Comment: I've fixed up some grammar, spelling and tags, but the question still isn't good. Would you please consider posting what you've tried, code samples, explain what you need etc. More information is very useful to people that are trying to help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i get the HTML5 Local storage values in server side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134737/how-can-i-get-the-html5-local-storage-values-in-server-side)

Comment: Client side am storing the data in localstorage localStorage.setItem("name","TestValue"); Now i want to read this localStorage value in MVC controller. how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The server doesn't have access to the client browser which is where the local data is stored . You will need to send the data to the server using javascript.

If you can give us some more information then i can give you an example that would solve your problem.

What version of MVC are you using (MVC2/3/4, WEB API, etc)?
What is the reason you need this data visible to the server?
Do you want the controller to do something with this data before it returns a new view?
etc.